# Map two dataframes, based on their group/id, with closer values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mapping

I have two datafames as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create dataset_1
data_set_1 = {'id': [1,
                     2,
                     3, 
                     4,
                     5,
                     ],
              'Available_Salary': [10,
                                   20,
                                   30,
                                   40,
                                   50,
                                   ],
              }

#Convert to dataframe_1
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_1)
print("\n df_1 = \n",df_1)



#Create dataset_2
data_set_2 = {'id': [1, 
                     2, 
                     3, 
                     4,
                     5,
                     6,
                     7,
                     8,
                     9,
                     10,
                     ],
              'Expected_Salary': [9,
                                  49,
                                  18,
                                  19,
                                  29,
                                  41,
                                  4,
                                  57,
                                  42,
                                  3,
                                  ],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_2
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_2)
print("\n df_2 = \n",df_2)
```

Here, visually I can say, 'Expected_Salary' 9 (with id=1), 'Expected_Salary' 4 (with id=7) and 'Expected_Salary' 3 (with id=10)  is closer to 'Available_Salary' 10 (with id=1).

Likewise, 'Expected_Salary' of 49 (with id=2) and 'Expected_Salary' 57 (with id=8) is closer to 'Available_Salary' 50 (with id=5), and so on.

This can be shown in below image file for better representation:

[image]

Now, I need to generate a new columns 'Salary_from_df_1' and 'id_from_df_1' in df_2 that will map with the id's of df_1 that signifies the closer salary.

For example, since the 'Expected_Salary' 9 (with id=1), 'Expected_Salary' 4 (with id=7) and 'Expected_Salary' 3 (with id=10)  is closer to 'Available_Salary' 10 (with id=1), so they will have 'Salary_from_df_1' as 10 and 'id_from_df_1' as 1. This looks as such:

[image]

The same logic follows for other id's of df_2 to map with df_1.

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate absolute difference of each salary in `df_2` from every available salary in `df_1`, then use `argmin` to get the index of minimum absolute diff, then use this index to yank the id values from `df_1` to `df_2`

```
i = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(df_2['Expected_Salary'].values, df_1['Available Salary'].values)).argmin(axis=1)
df_2['id_df1'] = df_1['id'].values[i]
```

---

```
   id  Expected_Salary  id_df1
0   1                9       1
1   2               49       5
2   3               18       2
3   4               19       2
4   5               29       3
5   6               41       4
6   7                4       1
7   8               57       5
8   9               42       4
9  10                3       1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShubhamSharma for your valuable comments. Also, could you please let me know how do I create the column'Salary_from_df_1' in df_2 as shown in the image file of my post?

Comment: Glad to help @NN_Developer. We can follow the similar approach for yanking salary values. `df_2['salary_df1'] = df_1['Available Salary'].values[i]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShubhamSharma for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Expected_Salary'),df2.sort_values('avail_salary'),left_on='Expected_Salary',right_on='avail_salary',direction='nearest').sort_values('id_x')
```

| id_x | Expected_Salary | id_y | avail_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 49 | 5 | 50 |
| 3 | 18 | 2 | 20 |
| 4 | 19 | 2 | 20 |
| 5 | 29 | 3 | 30 |
| 6 | 41 | 4 | 40 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 10 |
| 8 | 57 | 5 | 50 |
| 9 | 42 | 4 | 40 |
| 10 | 3 | 1 | 10 |

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ananthsankar for your valuable suggestions! I tried to implement your codes as it is. However, I am getting errors. Is the python version causing any problem? I am using Python 3.7.6. Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: Can you please specify the error? It would be helpful to narrow down the problems.

Comment: The error is @Ananthsankar:
`pd.merge_asof(df_1.sort_values('Expected_Salary'),df_2.sort_values('Available_Salary'),left_on='Expected_Salary',right_on='Available_Salary',direction='nearest').sort_values('id_x')
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6259, in sort_values
    k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)`

Comment: Do both dataframes contain the column 'id'? @NN_Developer If the error persists, it is likely due to a version error in Pandas, you can try upgrading both Pandas and Python to the latest versions. Upgrading to the latest versions can often fix bugs and compatibility issues.